# Getting data from Button inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a RecyclerView that displays a list of open games in a lobby. Each time the RecyclerView is updated, a button is added to the screen and I want to make it so that whenever a user clicks that button, it gets the ID of the section it is in.

So, games are added to database like this.

```
public void createLobbyGame () {
    User current = new User(userName, 0, getSide());
    String id = FCGames.push().getKey();

    gameMaker = new GameMaker(current, null, 0, numGames, false, false);

    FCGames.child(id)
            .setValue(gameMaker).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(FlipCoinLobby.this, "Game creation successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(FlipCoinLobby.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And that creates a node in my database that looks like this:

[image]

So right now the ID is set at 0 but that's just because I forgot to make the ID equal to the name of the node.

So when something is added to my database, it is drawn in the app with a button. I am not sure how to make this button display the ID of the database node that it correlates to.

This is the clicklistener I have setup for the button in my ViewHolder class

```
    Button joinButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.joinRV);
    joinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), gm.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Just having the getId() method called does not work at all, and I wasn't expecting it to. But I am kind of lost on how to grab the correlating ID of the button whenever I click it

---

Adapter Class:

```
    package com.example.brent.fifty_fifty;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import static android.view.LayoutInflater.*;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

GameMaker gm;
private OnItemClickListener listener;
private List<String> mData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

// data is passed into the constructor
MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.mInflater = from(context);
    this.mData = data;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> data, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mData = data;
    this.listener = listener;
}
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(String id);
}

// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

// binds the data to the TextView in each row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    String userName = mData.get(position);
    //Double wager = Double.parseDouble(mData.get(position));
    holder.userName.setText(userName);
    //holder.wager.setText(wager.toString());

}

// total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
}


// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView userName, wager;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.UsernameRV);
        //wager = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wagerRV);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button joinButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.joinRV);
        joinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(data);
                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "It worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void bind(final String data, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(mData.get(position), listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

// convenience method for getting data at click position
String getItem(int id) {
    return mData.get(id);
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at implementation of interface as Listener for recyclerview.

[Please look this implementation. This is good one if you are using JAVA.](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

Here clicklistener is set on itemView you just need to replace itemView with your button.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnButtonClickListener {
    void onButtonClick(String id);
}

private final List<String> items;
private final OnButtonClickListener listener;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items, OnButtonClickListener listener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout. recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Button joinButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        joinButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id. joinRV);
    }

    public void bind(final String id, final OnButtonClickListener listener) {
        joinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(id);
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

For your activity :

```
recycler.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(items, new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.OnButtonClickListener() {
@Override public void onButtonClick(String id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm trying to implement this now. ContentItem seems to be utilized quite a bit in this solution, but I cannot find the import for that class. Is there something I should be substituting in for ContentItem or am I just missing the import?

Comment: Never mind I read into the problem more and figured out that I am supposed to change ContentItem: I will continue working on this

Comment: contentItem is single object of the list  that is passed to recyclerview adapter when you initialize the adapter. can you post you adapter class too so that what exactly you need to pass.

Comment: I just posted my adapter class with the updated code from the link you sent me

Comment: I have passed String as my single object but I am not sure if that is correct. I also am not positive if this is just adding a clickListener so I will be able to click a button within the RecyclerView (which I already had implemented in a different way) Or if this will make it easier for me to retrieve data from my firebase database by linking the button to it's correlated ID

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. It's working now!